# save Capture session in documents directory using swift with avfoundation from device

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

Below snippet i am using  to save video in document directory(NSdata received from AVCaptureMoviefileOutput)

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    delegate?.recordingStopped?()

   var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: outputFileURL)
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory:AnyObject=paths[0]
    let dataPath=documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/MyFolder")
    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath)) {
        NSFileManager.defaultManager() .createDirectoryAtPath(dataPath as String, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)
    }

    var outputPathr = "\(dataPath)/TestproximityRwqxq.mp4"

    var success = data!.writeToFile(outputPathr as String, options: nil, error: nil)

}
```

Same code is working in simulator if used for other video (picking video from NSbundle and converting to NSdata), but not working with device,Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code is working Perfectly, We need to use device which has minimum iOS version 8.4(XCode 6.4) . device which has version below 8.4, is not getting the content of document directory using Swift2.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution I have modified for `swift5`, it is working for me.

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

    } else {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: outputFileURL) {

            let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
            let documentDirectory = paths[0]
            let docURL = URL(string: documentDirectory)!
            let dataPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent("/DIRECTORY_NAME")

            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString) {
              do {
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                    self.directoryURL = dataPath
                    print("Directory created successfully-\(dataPath.path)")
                } catch let error as NSError{
                    print("error creating directory -\(error.localizedDescription)");
                }
            }

            let outputPath = "\(dataPath.path)/filename.mp4"
            let success = data.write(toFile: outputPath, atomically: true)
            // saving video into photos album.
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputPath, nil, nil, nil)

        } 
    }
}
```